How to transmit and receive custom wireless data using Android's inbuilt baseband SoC?
I want to transmit and receive custom wireless data by using Android's baseband. So the question remains:

How to do it?
Is that true that the baseband operates on separate SoC & separate firmware?
If the baseband operates on different firmware, then can it be changed?
As we know, OTA updates exist on Android, so it means it's possible to upload a different firmware. But, is it possible to change the baseband firmware using a Cable-USB-PC method or not?

Case 2: if the baseband shares the same storage unit with the main OS, then it could be easier, but where to locate the firmware, what does the firmware extension look like, converting binary files to relative files?
Scenario 3: We can modify the stock ROM which contains baseband firmware. The stock ROM file contains baseband firmware which can be edited/modified or replaced with custom firmware, then we can upload it to the phone.
There could be multiple cases. Please help me.
I have experience in coding, custom Android firmware cooking, mobile rooting, extracting firmware of TVs/routers, etc.
Please remember my ultimate goal is to transmit and receive wireless custom data using a built-in Android baseband radio chip.

Similar to your prior question but your statement of "i have experience on coding, custom android firmware cooking, ..." and what you describe in 'scenario 3' imply otherwise as on Pixel device (custom ROM friendly) the binary blobs are available: https://developers.google.com/android/drivers Ideally if you have access to the datasheet for the chipsets you may be able to do something. Otherwise you are in the realm of black hat and security researchers looking for vulnerabilities not on open web.

There is no "Android inbuilt baseband". The baseband is phone specific, Android does only defines what API it has to provide, but the baseband itself is as far as I know developed by the phone manufacturer respectively the SoC manufacturer. Also baseband software is closed source and IP of who ever has developed it. Besides the API towards Android they are not documented. Feel free to extract and decompile a baseband yourself, however don't expect fast results.
